# Spring Framework 5.0.0.Final parent context not getting loaded

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-config

I was trying with latest spring 5.0.0.Final with my EAR project which has a parent context defined in **web.xml** using **context-param** 
 with param names **locatorFactorySelector** and **parentContextKey** but spring could not able to load the parent context. When i checked the **ContextLoaderListener** source code it seems like there is no logic applied to pick parent context. Here my question is does spring 5 provide any default implementation of **ContextLoader** which caters loading of parent context or spring 5 dropped, if not what is the approach to support this, do i have to implement our own ?

Comment: Any update from spring team? or do they left supporting through Stackoverflow ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i believe i'm having the same problem.  Beans are not being loaded from the shared context in 5, but did fine in 4.

Comment: No, not yet. we are still sticking with 4. The same was reported in the spring issue tracker https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16258 and they have moved the issue to github https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20805

Answer (score 2):

The loading of the parent context based on locatorFactorySelector were handled at ContextLoader#loadParentContext(). But they changed it to return null in this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/ac6aa53031b361e4ea8c74c6bdb4035715f37fb4#diff-86700632281e21d19c64ea752d94c2c9).

As said by the javadoc , I think you can create a new ContextLoaderListener and override this method to return the parent context:

```
public class FooContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener{

    @Override
    protected ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        //load and return the parent context ......
    }

}
```

Then use this ContextLoaderListener to start up Spring :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.foo.bar.FooContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

For me this below piece of code worked fine.

```
public class BeanFactoryContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BeanFactoryContextLoaderListener.class);
    
     @Override
        protected ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
            
         ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beanRefFactory.xml");
         
         return ctx;
        }

}
```

Obviously I added a listener too in web.xml.

Answer (score 2):

My team recently bumped into the same problem. We wanted to start using Webflux and it requires Spring 5.
Here is what I did:

1. Manually [reintroduce](https://code.lamsfoundation.org/fisheye/changelog/lams-github?cs=22ae678dec4e0fb8e09b5624fc58e1e5f6890243) BeanFactoryLocator mechanism. Take following classes from Spring 4, put it into your code and fix packages:

```
AbstractUrlMethodNameResolver
AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
BeanFactoryLocator
BeanFactoryReference
BootstrapException
ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator
DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
HandlerMethodInvocationException
HandlerMethodInvoker
HandlerMethodResolver
InternalPathMethodNameResolver
MethodNameResolver
NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException
ServletAnnotationMappingUtils
SingletonBeanFactoryLocator
SourceHttpMessageConverter
WebUtils
XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter
```

2. Following Subhranil's advice from this thread, use custom ContextLoaderListener which loads parent context same as in Spring 4. Then use it in web.xml.
3. In each WAR's spring-servlet.xml [add](https://code.lamsfoundation.org/fisheye/changelog/lams-github?cs=7d039f65ece5cc94cc6cd3694bbcef4fadcf62f2) `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` so it scans for controllers. [Accompanying beans](https://www.codelooru.com/2010/10/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do.html#:%7E:text=The%20annotations%20based%20MVC%20was,deprecated%20as%20of%20Spring%203.0.) like `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` are also needed.

It worked for us.

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is your context-param in any of your spring managed class you are looking for [`ServletContextAware`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html).

Just implement that class and override its method to get the `ServletContext` object. Later you can also get the ***context-params*** using the `ServletContext` object.

Check out a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20093759/3094731).

Comment: Not just that but still the above mentioned problem can be resolved this way.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the mechanism for locating the parent context was removed with [SPR-15154](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15154) (see also the corresponding Github issue [spring-framework#19720](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19720)).

One workaround is to extend `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and re-implement the `loadParentContext` method is described in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087660/107013).

There is probably a better way to solve parent context loading in Spring 5.x, which I still have to figure out.

Comment: That's well known but that doesn't work for EAR packaging