# Sharing parent spring context with child in spring 5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to share parent context with child in spring 5?

Using spring 4, we could pass `locatorFactorySelector` as `context-param`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:refFactory.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This support is removed from Spring 5 onward. What is the alternative to pass the parent context in web context?

Comment: See [SPR-15154](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15154) which is the issue that actually removed this. There are some solutions in the discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loading of the parent context based on `locatorFactorySelector` were handled at `ContextLoader#loadParentContext()`. But they changed it to `return null` in this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/ac6aa53031b361e4ea8c74c6bdb4035715f37fb4#diff-86700632281e21d19c64ea752d94c2c9).

As said by the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html#loadParentContext-javax.servlet.ServletContext-) , I think you can create a new `ContextLoaderListener` and  override this method to return the parent context:

```
public class FooContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener{

    @Override
    protected ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        //load and return the parent context ......
    }

}
```

Then use this `ContextLoaderListener` to start up Spring :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.foo.bar.FooContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Does extending XmlWebApplicationContext has any limitations?
Like 

public class FooConfigurableWebApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext {
    @Override
    public void setParent(@Nullable ApplicationContext parent) {
        super.setParent(getContext());
    }
}

and

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>w.x.y.z.FooConfigurableWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: Do you mean you use `ContextLoaderListener` to start ? but change `context-param` 's `contextClass`  to `FooConfigurableWebApplicationContext`?

Comment: Yes. Use default listener but change context class.

Comment: briefly look at the source codes and seem it will not work. Although your `FooConfigurableWebApplicationContext#setParent(parent)` will be invoked , but  the parent parameters is always loaded from the method that I suggest you to override...If you do not override , it will always be `null`..

Comment: Ok. I moved ahead with this problem. Now it appears velocity is also removed from spring 5. And i have no clue how to give velocity view resolver and velocity configurer bean definitions. 

Its totally different problem. But i hoped spring team would give an alternative or examples for legacy products.

Comment: For future reference: the above mentioned commit was part of the following feature: "Drop outdated BeanFactoryLocator / beanRefContext.xml mechanism" https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19720

Comment: DheerajJoshi and @MyKey_  We are still facing the same issue with the above mentioned workaround. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365412/not-able-to-refer-to-different-xml-using-spring-5-2-x. Can you please help us.

Comment: We had to change the custom spring bean factory to get this working..........  

public class CustomContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    @Override
    public ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        return CustomSpringBeanFactory.getApplicationContext();
    }
}