# Any replacement for locatorFactorySelector in Spring 5.3.7

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

We are using Spring 4.3.5 in our application. While we try to uplift the Spring to 5.3.7, we are not able to initialize beans(inside "beanRefFactory.xml") inside the below tag-

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
        <param-value>/beanRefFactory.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Upon searching we found that "locatorFactorySelector" or "LOCATOR_FACTORY_KEY_PARAM" have been deprecated in Spring 5.0.0.M5. Details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M4_to_5.0.0.M5/).

Kindly suggest if there is any other way to initialize "beanRefFactory.xml". **We are using XML based configuration.**

PS: have already gone through the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085902/sharing-parent-spring-context-with-child-in-spring-5), but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a custom class BeanFactoryContextLoader.java which extends ContextLoaderListener.

```
public class BeanFactoryContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BeanFactoryContextLoaderListener.class);
    
     @Override
        protected ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
            
         ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beanRefFactory.xml");
         
         return ctx;
        }

}
```

This worked for me.
By default Spring return null for the method "loadParentContext". You need to override it. [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html#loadParentContext-javax.servlet.ServletContext-) might give you some insight.