# BeanFactoryLocator alternative in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, spring5

We were using 4.2.x version of spring and we are using BeanFactoryLocator to create a factory from xml file.

**method to return Beanfactory**:

```
private BeanFactory createServicesContainer() {
        BeanFactoryLocator bfLocator = SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance("Connector.xml");
        BeanFactoryReference bfReference = bfLocator.useBeanFactory("bigBean");
        return bfReference.getFactory();
    }
```

**my Connector.xml file contains**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="false">

    <!--
        The Big Bean for accessing all the repository services. This factory bean serves as
        and umbrella bean for all the underlying repository services.
    -->
    <bean id="bigBean" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>sample1-connector.xml</value>
                <value>sample2-connector.xml</value>
                <value>sample3-connector.xml</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Now how can make changes it to work in Spring 5.x**

Comment: Load the files from `bigBean` into your context instead of the `beanRefFactory` thing.

Comment: BeanFactory factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Connector.xml");
BeanFactory fs=(BeanFactory) factory.getBean("bigBean");
return fs;                                                          will these works?

Comment: Just ditch that file and just load the `sample1-connector.xml` etc. directly with your `ContextLoaderListener` or use `<import resource />` in an xml file to get these loaded to (you could change your `beanRefContext.xml` to that and let the `ContextLoaderListener` load that file.

Comment: i didn't get could you please give me an example

Comment: The example is in the comments. Replace what you have now in your `beanRefContext.xml` with `<import resourse="classpath:sample1-connector.xml />` and then let your `ContextLoaderListener` load the `beanRefContext.xml` (or just rename it to `applicationContext.xml` so it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: i think ContextLoaderListener is used in web.xml to automate the creation of the ApplicationContext where we need to specify multiple xml files under contextconfigloaciton, is this correct..... but here i need to create applicationContext/Beanfactory in a method and return to caller..

Comment: Why? That seems very inefficient as it will recreate things each time. I would no mark this question to be closed as apparently there is more information needed to help you. You haven't included all the details in here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242723/discussion-between-bharath-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Someone solved it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902115/spring-framework-5-0-0-final-parent-context-not-getting-loaded/70094114#70094114)